# Why does jQuery code in window.load work sometimes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to hide a div which was dynamically added by accordion.js at runtime, but it's hiding sometime and sometimes not.

Here is my code:

```
function hideTab2() {
  $(window).load(function(){
    $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(1).addClass('hidden');
    $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(2).addClass('hidden');
  });
}
```

`hideTab2()` function call from codebehind.

Comment: Why are you using $(window).load...... You should delete this and then check.

Comment: Because the .panel class added dynamically , if i'm not use window.load() then .panel 
class is not found

Comment: Can you show us some more code and information what you are actually trying to do .

Comment: I just want to hide div by (.panel) class,is any alternatives to $(window).load,and .panel class div added by runtime not present in page

Comment: Thats why i am asking you to show some code. Because we need to see when you are calling this function.

Comment: if (Request.QueryString["school"] != null && Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["school"]) != "")
            {ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hidetab2", "hideTab2();",true);}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76855/discussion-between-ghanshyam-lakhani-and-rohit-arora).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this, It will call after your page render completely.

```
$(window).bind("load", function () {
    $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(1).addClass('hidden');
    $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(2).addClass('hidden');
});
```

As discuss with questioner,

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<% if(Request.QueryString["status"] == "add") { %>
    $(window).bind("load", function () {
        $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(1).addClass('hidden');
        $("#myaccordian-accordion").find('.panel ').eq(2).addClass('hidden');
    });
<%} %>

</head>
```

Comment: When you calling `hideTab2()` function from code behind?

Comment: When the query string not available (means new record) in url then hidetab2() is call

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can write that code in your .ASPX page. I think it will solved your problem.